# InfluxQL/Flux: Summarizing two measurements

Tags: influxdb

I have an InfluxDB 1.8 installation. Each query returns individual float values. How can I merge them into one sum?

**Query #1**

```
SELECT last("energyRoof1") AS "PowerRoof1" FROM "pvsystem"."autogen"."PV"
Result: 50.568
```

**Query #2**

```
SELECT last("energyRoof2") AS "PowerRoof2" FROM "pvsystem"."autogen"."PV"
Result: 123.367
```

Expected Result: `173,935`

Answer (score 0):

If the two datapoints are at the same timestamp than you can do:

```
SELECT last("energyRoof1") + last("energyRoof2") FROM "pvsystem"."autogen"."PV"
```